# Pygame - Trouble creating multiple asteroid objects in an Asteroids game

Tags: pygame

I've been working on a game made to replicate Asteroids with my own additions here and there. The issue I've ran into is not understanding how exactly I should go about making multiple asteroid objects of the same class. I have the basic code for the asteroids in terms of initializing and updating that currently just creates and keeps track of one asteroid. I've looked into other posts and examples of how you might go about making multiple objects of the same class, but none of them fit with how my code is set up. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Import Modules
import pygame
import math
import random

#Movement Function
def calculate_new_xy(old_xy,speed,direction):
    new_x = old_xy[0] + (speed*math.cos(direction))
    new_y = old_xy[1] + (speed*math.sin(direction))
    return new_x, new_y

#Draw Text Function
def drawText(msg, color, x, y, s, center=True):
    screen_text = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", s).render(msg, True, color)
    if center:
        rect = screen_text.get_rect()
        rect.center = (x, y-50)
    else:
        rect = (x, y)
    display.blit(screen_text, rect)

#Initialize Variables

#Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

#Display Height/Width
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

#Asteroid Class
class Asteroid:
    #Initialize values
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0)):
        #Asteroid sprite
        self.asteroid = pygame.image.load("asteroid.png").convert()
        self.image = self.asteroid
        #Rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        #Initialize random starting angle
        self.angle = random.randint(0, 360)
        #Asteroid random Speed
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 5)
        #Asteroid random direction
        self.direction = math.radians(random.randint(0, 360))

    #Update asteroid object
    def update(self):
        #Constantly rotate asteroid
        self.angle -= 3 % 360

        #Get image angle and position
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.asteroid, self.angle*-1)

        #Use rectangle to get center of image
        #Save ship's current center.
        x, y = self.rect.center
        #Replace old rect with new rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Put the new rect's center at old center.
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

        #Move Asteroid
        self.rect.center = calculate_new_xy(self.rect.center,self.speed,self.direction)

        #Screen Border
        #Moves the player to the opposite side of the screen if they go outside the border
        if self.rect.x > display_width:
            self.rect.x = -50
        elif self.rect.x < -50:
            self.rect.x = display_width
        elif self.rect.y > display_height:
            self.rect.y = -50
        elif self.rect.y < -50:
            self.rect.y = display_height


#Player Class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #Initialize ship sprite, angle lines, and rectangle
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0), size=(200, 200)):
        #Player sprite
        self.ship = pygame.image.load("ship.png").convert()
        self.image = self.ship
        #Rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        #Initialize angle
        self.angle = 0

    #Update player object
    def update(self):
        #Rotation
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: self.angle -= 3 % 360
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.angle += 3 % 360

        #Get image angle and position
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.ship, self.angle*-1)

        #Use rectangle to get center of image
        #Save ship's current center.
        x, y = self.rect.center
        #Replace old rect with new rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Put the new rect's center at old center.
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

        #Convert angle to radians
        self.direction = math.radians(self.angle-90)

        #Increase speed if Up is pressed
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: self.speed = 5
        else: self.speed = 0

        #Move Ship
        self.rect.center = calculate_new_xy(self.rect.center,self.speed,self.direction)

        #Screen Border
        #Moves the player to the opposite side of the screen if they go outside the border
        if self.rect.x > display_width:
            self.rect.x = -50
        elif self.rect.x < -50:
            self.rect.x = display_width
        elif self.rect.y > display_height:
            self.rect.y = -50
        elif self.rect.y < -50:
            self.rect.y = display_height

#Main Function
def main():
    #Player starting position
    player = Player(pos=(400, 300))
    #Asteroid starting position
    asteroids = Asteroid(pos=(400, 300))

    #Initialize Game state
    gameState = "Menu"
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #closes game
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
        #Game Menu
        while gameState == "Menu":
            #Fill background
            display.fill((0,0,0))
            #Display menu text
            drawText("ASTEROIDS", white, display_width / 2, display_height / 2, 150)
            drawText("Press any key to START", white, display_width / 2, display_height / 2 + 120, 40)
            #Check game start or end
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    gameState = "Playing"
            pygame.display.update()
            #Low frame rate for menu
            clock.tick(5)

        #Update player
        player.update()

        #Udate asteroids
        asteroids.update()

        #Display background
        display.fill((0,0,0))

        #Draw player
        display.blit(player.image, player.rect)

        #Draw asteroids
        display.blit(asteroids.image, asteroids.rect)

        #Makes updates to the game screen
        pygame.display.update()

        #Frame rate
        clock.tick(60)

#Initialize Game
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #initialize pygame
    pygame.init()

    #initialize display settings
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Asteroids')

    #initialize game clock
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #start main function
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 ways to do this in pygame

1) use a spritegroup

2) use a list

You havent set up your class for a spritegroup so i'll start with the list

You have `asteroids = Asteroid(pos=(400, 300))` which is good, because to make more all you need to do is `asteroids = [Asteroid(pos=(400, 300))]` now you have a list with 1 asteroid. To make more, you can call `Asteroid` more times so

```
asteroids = [Asteroid(pos=(400, 300)) for x in range(10)]
```

Now you have 10 asteroids, but they start in the same position so

```
asteroids = [Asteroid(pos=(400 + (x*30), 300)) for x in range(10)]
```

Now we have 10 asteroids 30 pixels apart

To update and draw them, loop through the list

```
#Update asteroids
for asteroid in asteroids:
    asteroid.update()


#same for draw
#Draw asteroids
for asteroid in asteroids:
    display.blit(asteroid.image, asteroid.rect)
```

if you have lots of asteroids, it would be a good idea to combine these loops this is still fine.

---

SpriteGroups

To setup a class for a spritegroup, you need it to inherit the Sprite class

```
class Asteroid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Initialize values
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #initialize the Sprite class
```

then you can make a spritegroup

```
#Asteroid starting position
asteroids = pygame.sprite.Group()
for x in range(10):
    asteroids.add(Asteroid(pos=(400 + (x*30), 300))) #all 30 pixels apart
```

and to update them, you can do the same thing you are doing now

```
#Update asteroids
asteroids.update()
```

To draw, even easier than what you are doing now

```
#Draw asteroids
asteroids.draw(display)
```